# ensure Coroutine completion in RoomDatabase.Callback

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am using RoomDatabase.Callback to override and call OnCreate to pre-fill my Room database with data.
How do I ensure this is completed before continuing?
The issue I'm having is I don't know when prePopulateDatabase will be completed, and it's moving on in the code without this necessary data.

Code is;

```
private class AppDatabaseCallback(private val scope: CoroutineScope) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        super.onCreate(db)
        INSTANCE?.let { database ->
            scope.launch {
                val puzzleDao = database.puzzleDao()
                prePopulateDatabase(puzzleDao)
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun prePopulateDatabase(puzzleDao: PuzzleDao) {
        val startingData = StartingData()
        puzzleDao.insertAllPuzzles(startingData.getStartingPuzzles())
    }
}
```

and the fragment code that calls it;

```
    loadPuzzlesJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

        // this either returns the existing roomdb, or creates it and fills it with the pre-data
        val puzzleDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext(), CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)).puzzleDao()

        // data should now be available
        // PROBLEM - this is running before prePopulateDatabase is, so no data is returned
        allPuzzles = puzzleDao.getAllPuzzles().toMutableList()

        if (allPuzzles.isEmpty()) {
            // puzzles not found, send to error screen
            errorFound(ErrorType.PuzzlesNotFound)
        }

        loadPuzzlesJob?.cancelAndJoin()
    }


fun getDatabase(context: Context, coroutineScope: CoroutineScope): AppDatabase {
        val tempInstance = INSTANCE
        if (tempInstance == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "mydbname"
                ).addCallback(AppDatabaseCallback(coroutineScope)).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        } else {
            return tempInstance
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the contents of your `AppDatabase.getDatabase()` function?

Comment: AppDatabase.getDatabase code now added